# Under WordPress, where do duplicate URLs come from that append "French%20Together%20Course_files/" to the end of the correct URL many times?

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-content

I created a sales page (`https://example.com/course/`).

But now, I see lots of duplicate pages that look like the (very long) link below.

Any idea what causes this and how I can stop it?

`https://example.com/course/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/French%20Together%20Course_files/track`

Comment: *Where* do you see these links?

Comment: The "_files" part makes me think it is part of Firefox's "save complete webpage".   It creates a directory with the encoded title of the page "_files".     Is the title of your page "French Together Course"?   That doesn't explain the massive duplication, or why WordPress is serving up duplicate content for it though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Yes, the title of the page is "French Together Course". I see these links when I audit the website with Ahrefs Site Audit tool.

Comment: I think I found the source of the duplicates. There is this line in my code. Not sure what it's for:

<script type="text/javascript" src="./French Together Course_files/track"></script>